# Why do I keep dying in melee battles?

Tags: xbox-one, star-wars-battlefront-2015

Every once in awhile when I sneak up on someone and melee them to get the extra points, it takes more than one hit, is this because of the gun i'm using? Or is it because of where i'm hitting? Or just the game's collision detection?

Comment: Is this about the original Star Wars Battlefront, or the new one which should be tagged  sw-battlefront-2015?

Comment: A body melee takes 50 health, so anyone with over 50 will always take two, IIRC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably the melee damage amounts:

- Melee to the head does 100 points of damage.
- Melee to the body does 50. Therefore two body hits are needed if the player starts at full health.

So yes, your targeting does affect the melee in SW Battlefront 2015, unlike most other games. This is also never communicated to you by DICE in any documentation or in-game tutorials or tips.

(Keep in mind, mediocre netcode settings that DICE uses also mean sometimes the melee just misses when it appears like it shouldn't, or vice versa for the opponent. Not much you can do about that since they lock down all the settings unlike most other good games, for example games based on Valve's Source engine. But if you have a decent, stable internet connection, this doesn't happen too often. If it takes a second hit, the first was most likely a body shot.)

However, why you are *dying* in melee battles might be other issues. ;-) If you sneak up behind them as you say, hopefully you should be able to hit them twice before they notice you unless you do something else to give yourself away, or they have buddies, etc.

Comment: I read elsewhere on this site that the damage from the melee depends on the gun, so that some of the large guns are one-shot kills to the body.

Comment: That's possible... I haven't done science on every gun yet.

Comment: I had absolutely no idea that you could melee to the head!